# Javascript loop semi working

Tags: javascript, html

EDIT: I fixed the typo but nothing changes

I have the following array in a JS file:

```js
var directory = [
    {  type: "file", name: "file1.txt"  },
    {  type: "file", name: "file2.txt"  },
    {  type: "directory", name: "HTML Files", files: [
        {  type: "file", name: "file1.html"  },
        {  type: "file", name: "file2.html"  }
    ]},
    {  type: "file", name: "file3.txt"  },
    {  type: "directory", name: "JavaScript Files", files: [
        {  type: "file", name: "file1.js"  },
        {  type: "file", name: "file2.js"  },
        {  type: "file", name: "file3.js"  }
    ]}
];
```

Also in JS file:

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var directoryContainer = document.querySelector("#outputList1");
    var directoryList = "<ul>";
    for (var i = 0; i < directory.length; i++)
    {
        if (directory[i].type == "file")
        {
            directoryList += "<li>" + directory[i].name + "</li>";
        }
        else if (directory[i].type == "directory")
        {
            directoryList += "<li>" + directory[i].name + "<ul>" + "<li>";
            for (var j = 0; j < directory[i].length; j++)
            {
                directoryList += directory[j].files.name + "</li>";
            }
            directoryList += "</ul>";
            directoryList += "</li>";
        }
    }
    directoryList += "</ul>";
    directoryContainer.innerHTML = directoryList;
};
```

In my HTML file:

```html
<h3> Files </h3>
<head>
    <script src = "js/list.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id = "outputList1"></div>
</body>
```

It then prints on my website:

```
Files   // title

-file1.txt

-file2.txt

-HTML Files

    //Nothing here

-file3.txt

-JavaScript Files

   //Nothing here
```

However in the areas where I commented nothing here, it's supposed to print the filenames when the type is a directory. The error is occurring somewhere in my for loop, but I'm not sure where. The final answer should look like this

```
Files // title

-file1.txt

-file2.txt

-HTML Files

    - file1.html

    - file2.html


-file3.txt

-JavaScript Files

    -file1.js

    -file2.js

    -file3.js
```

Comment: `direcrotyList`

Comment: second loop is looping over the wrong thing

Comment: `direcrotyList += directory[j].files.name + "</li>"`  should be `directoryList += directory[j].files.name + "</li>"`.

Comment: @ObsidianAge You typed the same thing twice :D

Comment: @WorkMan -- Untrue. The first one has a typo, like your code, which is why your loop isn't working correctly ;)

Comment: LOOOL. I was literally staring for 5 minutes thinking I missed a dot or a +=. I see the typo now :DDDDD

Comment: Fixed the typo but theres still no change

Comment: `for (var j = 0; j < directory[i].length; j++)` should be `for (var j = 0; j < directory[i].files.length; j++)` . LIkewise `directoryList += directory[j].files.name + "</li>" ` is `directoryList += directory[i].files[j].name + "</li>" `

Comment: Also, your algorithm is broken and will only traverse two levels deep. You should use recursion or an iterative traversal algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems. The typo, as mentioned in the comments, and your inner `for` loop is iterating over `directory[i]`, instead of `directory[i].files`. So change:

```
for (var j = 0; j < directory[i].length; j++) {...}
```

to

```
for (var j = 0; j < directory[i].files.length; j++) {...}
```

Also, might I suggest looking into recursion? It's a hard idea to comprehend at first, but you'll find uses for it over and over. Using it here would dramatically reduce your code, making it cleaner, more readable, much more robust (as you would then be able to nest files and folders endlessly, just like they are on a real system), and less error-prone. I don't think you would have had this problem if you'd done something like this:

```
function mapFiles(files) {
    return '<ul><li>' + files.map(function(item) {
        if (item.type === 'file') {
            return item.name
        }
        return item.name + mapFiles(item.files)
    }).join('</li><li>') + '</li></ul>'
}

var directoryList = mapFiles(directory)
```

Check it out on this [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/fa91qhxv/)

Comment: yeah my class is going to be going over recursion in a few weeks so I'll definitely be using it :)

Answer (score 0):

Some issues:

- The HTML tags are in the wrong order: `h3` should be within the `body` element.
- You have a typo in `direcrotyList`
- `directory[j].files.name` should be `directory[i].files[j].name` and `directory[i].length` should be `directory[i].files.length`
- This solution will not work if you have sub-(sub-)directories. Recursion is a solution to that.

Here is how you could do it:

```js
function getFilesHtml(directory) {
    return '<ul>' + directory.map(function (entry) {
        return '<li>' + entry.name + 
            (entry.type == 'file' ? '' : getFilesHtml(entry.files))
        + '</li>';
    }).join('') + '</ul>';
}

window.onload = function() {
    var directory = [
        {type: "file", name: "file1.txt"},
        {type: "file", name: "file2.txt"},
        {type: "directory", name: "HTML Files", files: [
            {type: "file", name: "file1.html"},
            {type: "file", name: "file2.html"}
        ]},
        {type: "file", name: "file3.txt"},
        {type: "directory", name: "JavaScript Files", files: [
            {type: "file", name: "file1.js"},
            {type: "file", name: "file2.js"},
            {type: "file", name: "file3.js"}
        ]}
    ];

    document.querySelector("#outputList1").innerHTML = getFilesHtml(directory);
};
```

```html
<h3> Files </h3>
<div id = "outputList1"></div>
```